# What is the query to choose the number of people living at each address?

Tags: sql, select, count

What is the query to choose the number of people living at each address?

***(data should be in the form of ‘Address - Number of residents’)***
table - Contact.CL_Info

```
FIO Address Phone   Age
ФИО1    Адрес1  123 11
ФИО2    Адрес2  123 12
ФИО3    Адрес3  123 13
ФИО4    Адрес4  123 14
ФИО5    Адрес2  123 14
ФИО6    Адрес3  123 13
ФИО7    Адрес5  123 12
ФИО8    Адрес6  123 11
ФИО9    Адрес7  (null)  15
ФИО10   Адрес8  123 21
```

Answer (score 4):

You could issue a `count` and group it by the `address`:

```
SELECT   address, count(*)
FROM     Contact.CL_Info
GROUP BY address
```

Comment: and  result is a - (data should be in the form of ‘Address - Number of residents’)  ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GROUP BY` Address to get the count for each address.

```
SELECT Address, COUNT(*) AS AddressCount  
FROM Contact.CL_Info 
GROUP BY Address
```